# Connecting a C++ Backend to a C# Frontend to Upload to Azure Storage Blobs

Tags: c#, c++, .net, azure

Recently, I've been playing around with connecting a C# frontend (.NET 6.0) to a C++ backend (which is built as a .dll) using a CLR Class Library(.NET). I created a simple addition function in my C++ project that takes two ints as arguments and returns their sum. My CLR code basically wraps it and builds into another .dll which I then was able to call from my C# code, inputting the two ints and getting the result returned, which worked fine.

Next when I tried to install the azure.storage.blobs nuGet package in my C# project, to test if I could maybe use the C++ project to generate files and use the C# project to upload them. I am now getting a dependency error:

Error   CS1705  Assembly 'MathOperationsCLI' with identity 'MathOperationsCLI, Version=1.0.8513.16241, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I made sure my MathOperationsCLI project was correctly targeting the .NET 6.0 framework and also checked the .csproj file, which showed it was correct. I made sure that no other packages were installed into the CLI project that could have other dependencies. I am at a loss of how to fix this.
I am also wondering if this is the correct way to go about uploading files to Azure storage blobs from a C++ backend, would be great if anyone else has any other suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: The compiler found (a copy of) `MathOperationsCLI` which compiled with (.Net) Runtime Version=7.0.0.0. but your code is compiled with (.Net) Runtime Version=6.0.0.0. Try to delete all copied instances of it and rebuild it.

Comment: @SHR Thanks! I deleted everything from the output folders and rebuilt and it worked, thanks for your suggestion. Must have been a sneaky .net 7.0 build hiding. Will upvote your comment when I get some rep :)